# Understanding Small Parsimony, Sankoff's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, evolutionary-algorithm, phylogeny

Small Parsimony Problem:
Find the most parsimonious labeling of the internal vertices in an evolutionary tree.
Input: Tree T with each leaf labeled by an m-character string.
Output: Labeling of internal vertices of the tree T minimizing the parsimony score.

I am referring to the image at the bottom of this post. I am simply trying to follow the provided example. I understand the first step is to label the four leaves A, C, T, G (as we are provided this input), and that we do so by setting the appropriate one character to 0 and the rest of the alphabet of characters to infinity in the array of each leaf.

In the next step of the image, we analyze the two internal nodes that are not the root. I understand this process as well. For instance, in the left internal node, we get the array A/9, T/7, G/8, C/9. Each of these four values were calculated as the left child (A) and right child (C), plus the score penalties. For instance, A/9 was taken as the 0+0 (left child score of 0 + penalty of A->A), plus 0+9 (right child score of 0 + penalty of C->A).

What I am confused about, however, is how the root was calculated. It is a different situation than considering the leaves that have values of infinity (such that adding a small penalty makes no difference, the infinity score is not even considered).

When I drew it out, it seems that A/14, T/9, 10/G, 15/c of the root is calculated as such: For A/14, we take the minimum of four possible values. The first value is the case of left and right children being A's (9+7+2(0) = 16), the second value is the case of left and right children being T's (7+2+2(3) = 14), the third value is the case of left and right children being G's (8+2+2(4) = 18), the fourth value is the case of left and right children being C's (9+8+2(9) = 35). The minimum of these four values is min(16, 14, 18, 35) = 14, which means the left and right children are T if the root is A.

If I continue in this manner, I get the same values as the book for the root (14, 9, 10, 15), where the minimum is 9, indicating that the root is T (and both its children are also T).

However, is this the right logic? I feel there can be more combinations than only exploring four values per character of the root. I especially feel strange that I would only consider the four cases such that the children must be the same character (A and A, T and T, G and G, C and C).

So my question is, is this just a coincidence that this works in this problem? If it is correct, why would I not need to consider cases when the two children are of different characters? If it is incorrect, what would be the right way to calculate the root in this example (I prefer to see numbers related to this specific problem, because I still go cross-eyed trying to figure out complicated equations).

Thank you.

[image]
In case it is hard to read, the arrays of the vertices in post-order are [0, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, 0], [9, 7, 8, 9], [inf, 0, inf, inf], [inf, inf, 0, inf], [7, 2, 2, 8], [14, 9, 10, 15]

Answer (score 4):

Well, this answer is a bit late but I'll chime in anyway.

Yes, it is just a coincidence that your solution happens to work. To calculate the value of A at an internal node in the tree, you are supposed to consider the minimum cost from A to {A,C,T,G} in the left branch, plus the minimum cost from A to {A,C,T,G} in the right branch.

So for the root node, to calculate the value of A:

```
LEFT            RIGHT

0 3 4 9         0 3 4 9
9 7 8 9         7 2 2 8
-------        ---------
9 10 12 18      7 5 6 17     min = 9+5 = 14 (A)
```

You then repeat this procedure for {C,T,G} to get the other values.

```
 LEFT            RIGHT

3 0 2 4         3 0 2 4
9 7 8 9         7 2 2 8 
-------        ---------
12 7 10 13      10 2 4 12    min = 7+2 = 9  (T)

4 2 0 4         4 2 0 4
9 7 8 9         7 2 2 8
-------        ---------
13 9 8 13       11 4 2 12    min = 8+2 = 10 (G)

9 4 4 0         9 4 4 0
9 7 8 9         7 2 2 8
-------        ---------
18 11 12 9      16 6 6 8     min = 9+6 = 15 (C)
```